# How to move files found with pattern and move to another subdirectory in unix

Tags: unix, find, xargs

I have this:

```
.
├── dirA
│   └── ProdA
│       ├── Brief
│       │   └── Form.xlsx
│       ├── Results
│       └── Studies
└── dirB
    └── BrandB
        └── ProdB
            ├── Brief
            │   └── Form.xlsx
            └── Results
```

and i want this:

```
.
├── dirA
│   └── ProdA
│       ├── Brief
│       ├── Results
│       └── Studies
│           └── Form.xlsx
└── dirB
    └── BrandB
        └── ProdB
            ├── Brief
            └── Results
            └── Studies  
                └── Form.xslx
```

So basically i have to find files Form.xlsx and move it from subdirectory Brief to subdirectory Studies (create it if it does not exists), both at the same level.

when i do:

```
find . -name '*.xlsx' -exec mv '{}' ../Studies ';'
```

I got:

```
.
├── dirA
│   └── ProdA
│       ├── Brief
│       ├── Results
│       └── Studies
└── dirB
    └── BrandB
        └── ProdB
            ├── Brief
            └── Results
```

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted this Q. Much better than average relating to directory problems! BUT ... If there is no target dir existing, I would expect `mv {} ../Studies` to just rename the file to `Studies`, It's not going be able to read your mind and make dir instead. Best to cycle thru target dirs, chk `for d in *; do if ! [ -d ./path/$d/Studies ]  ; then mkdir path/$d/Studies ; fi ; done` or similar. Then run you `find` command. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `..` to get the matched file's parent directory, use `dirname` instead.

```sh
find . -name "*.xlsx" -exec sh -c 'mv {} "$(dirname $(dirname {}))/Studies/"' \;
```

Have a try! :)